# Idea select maven profile sometimes not working

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I want to make maven package width my specify redis auth config,but when I select dev profile,sometimes the value of 'redis password' value is dev sometimes it is production's value.I don't know why!

pom.xml

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <redis.pass>123456</redis.pass>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>production</id>
        <properties>
            <redis.pass>K31f65ds095f1GDaakf0387</redis.pass>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

redis.properties

```
redis.password=${redis.pass}
```

[This picture shows it is working well.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXBsq.png)

[This picture shows 'redis.pass' value is wrong.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOfQi.png)

Comment: See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-179089

Comment: It worked,thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem happend again.
But I think I solved this problem by adding compile maven goal to run configurations.
[This works well.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MOFh.png)